# Phaser: Calling update function not working

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Link to the repository: https://github.com/kdorosh/ProjectLazarus

I'm creating a Mass Effect themed game using Phaser. There is a Normandy ship object, and belonging to it is a group of laser beams (named torpedos).

I'm trying to call the update functions of the individual torpedos as I call the update function for the Normandy, but for some reason the torpedo.update() isn't being called. Can someone help me figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's still relevant for you or if you got it working by now:

After having a look through your project in general and the Game.js in particular it seems to me that you only need to add your `updateTorpedoes(torpedoes, camVel)` (with the values you need for torpedoes and camVel) to your update function in Game.js similar as you did with your update function for the Normandy ship object.